# Stay on Top layer or go to Power Plane

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I am reviewing a 4 layers PCB (2 layers + GND + Power layer with different rails on it) which is hosting a Lipo battery charger being capable to deliver up to 2.5A on the output named SYS.

We have one track wich is connecting two components (an inductor and a capacitor). We are hesitating wether we should keep this track on the top layer or if we should better create two vias and send the track on the power layer.

What is best ?

PS: We are not on high frequencies

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45170/discussion-on-question-by-chris-stay-on-top-layer-or-go-to-power-plane).

Answer (score 2):

*[I'm posting this as an answer, because I'd like to post a picture.  This is more of an extended comment than answer.]*

> We are not on high frequencies

The trace in question is a part of the power path circuit.  It's not switching.  But if we look at the parts of the layout that are switching, they are badly laid out.  Switch mode converters can be layout-sensitive.
[It's somewhat hard to discuss this, because components aren't designated on the layout.]

> What is best ?

A good (possibly best) approach is to try to make your layout close to that of the [bq24165 evaluation module](http://www.ti.com/tool/bq24165evm-720) created by TI.

[image]
(source: p.12 and ff [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu669/sluu669.pdf).)